# Incomplete understanding of how an object in a list is counted

Tags: python

If string are lists, I'm not understanding how the code counts the list. More specifically, i counts from 0,1,2,... but returns a string?

I've tried using print(word[i]), print(i), print(int(i))

```
word = input('\n')

for i in word:

    if i.isupper() == True:

        print(i)
```

If the input is 'STrinG', the expected result is [0,1,5] but actual results is S T G

Comment: Hint: Check what i is. It's not a number. `i.isupper()` wouldn't make much sense if i were a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: Strings are not lists.even if they were, neither strings not lists behave this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop iterates through the string, *not* through the indices.  `i` takes on the values in "STrinG" in order, one letter at a time.  If you want the indices, you need to iterate through that, instead:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i].isupper():
        print(i)
```

Better yet, use `enumerate` to do both:

```
for i, char in enumerate(word):
    if char.isupper():
        print(i)
```

Does that get you moving?